# Completion Handler or function for this style of animation

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I can't find an animation completion handler/function for this kind of style of code.

I didn't use the Animation block provided that has a build in completion function once animation is complete, because I need to be in control of the repetition process.

What I need to do is if this animation is completed, the image should be `removeFromSuperView()`. Is there a workaround for this one?

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {
    var repeatCount = Float(10.0)
    var duration = 2.0

    //if finished, remove image using image.removeFromSuperview()

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(duration)
    UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(repeatCount)
    image.frame = CGRectMake(160, 300, 50, 50)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: @nhgrif, Let me rephrase it again... I am not asking how this should be translated from Objective-C to swift. Please read my question before concluding on down voting a question. Thank you.

Comment: "I didn't use the Animation block provided that has a build in completion function once animation is complete, because I need to be in control of the repetition process." Well, you're wrong about that. If you don't understand how to "control the repetition process" of the new-style view animation block calls, ask about _that_. I can tell you how to attach a repeat count of 10 to the new-style block, for example. Nevertheless, I have answered the question you did ask.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the reply. I did try to search about the repetition process online and it seems that no one is answering that question. So in the end, I have used the older style since it has the repeatCount function that I need. So how do you control the repetition process in the animation block? or should I open a new question in stack overflow just for that. Thank you.

Comment: I just told you, yes I do have a way to do it, and yes you should ask it as a separate question. But meanwhile please note that I have answered _this_ question! If my answer is useful, please consider accepting it (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using the old style `beginAnimations` / `commitAnimations` structure. But if you are going to use it, then simply give the animation a delegate with `setAnimationDelegate:` and specify a selector to be called when the animation ends with `setAnimationDidStopSelector:`, as I describe here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_modifying_an_animation_block

Answer (score 0):

You really, seriously, should use block-based animation; but if you must, set the delegate and callback(s) before committing the animations, declared right by the other setAnimationXXX functions.

```
// no getters. if called outside animation block, these setters have no effect.
class func setAnimationDelegate(delegate: AnyObject?) // default = nil
class func setAnimationWillStartSelector(selector: Selector) // default = NULL. -animationWillStart:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context
class func setAnimationDidStopSelector(selector: Selector) // default = NULL. -animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

Also, what you're declaring here

```
    [UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)]
```

is "an array containing the result of beginAnimations, which is Void". This is not useful in any conceivable context.